# What is the equivalent of `apt list` in FreeBSD?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, pkg

I have just started using FreeBSD again after some years of staying away from *BSD based systems (with the exception of macOS). I am using FreeBSD 11.0 and 12.0.

To manage packages, `pkg` seems rather intuitive, and in fact the commands are pretty similar being `pkg update`, `pkg upgrade`, `pkg search` and `pkg autoremove`.

However, what is the equivalent of `apt list` or `dpkg -l` for having a list of the already installed packages? I somewhat remember and have found a page detailing it is `pkg_info`, however the command is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pkg_info` usage is deprecated, and hence your confusion.

In fact, the appropriate command to list the already installed FreeBSD packages is `pkg info`.

From `man pkg`

> info    Display information about installed packages.

```
$ pkg info | tail
python27-2.7.13_1              Interpreted object-oriented programming language
readline-6.3.8                 Library for editing command lines as they are typed
screen-4.5.0_2                 Multi-screen window manager
sdig-0.45_1                    Translate IP/DNS/WINS/MAC address into port description
tmux-2.3_2                     Terminal Multiplexer
unbound-1.6.1                  Validating, recursive, and caching DNS resolver
vm-bhyve-1.1.5                 Management system for bhyve virtual machines
wget-1.19                      Retrieve files from the Net via HTTP(S) and FTP
xextproto-7.3.0                XExt extension headers
xproto-7.0.31                  X11 protocol headers
```

Please see the FreeBSD wiki [Pkg Primer](https://wiki.freebsd.org/PkgPrimer) that details the usage of the `pkg` command, and the equivalent usage of the deprecated pkg_* commands.